React JS how to properly set Cookies using custom reactHooks?
I am creating the login functionalities of my website but having trouble with setting the Cookie with the token from my backend. The token is being returned properly and is setting the user in the UserContext, however the part where the token is to be stored in the browser Cookie (such as when viewed in the browser developer options Application tab) it is not showing or being set. I have no idea whether the issue is in the Login.jsx or in the useStorage.js. Here are the current codes:
frontend/src/hooks/useStorage.js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue) {
    return useStorage(key, defaultValue, window.localStorage);
};

function useSessionStorage(key, defaultValue) {
    return useStorage(key, defaultValue, window.sessionStorage);
};

function useCookiesStorage(key, defaultValue, options) {
    return useStorage(key, defaultValue, null, options);
};

function useStorage(key, defaultValue, storageObject, options) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        if (storageObject) {
            const jsonValue = storageObject.getItem(key);
            if (jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue);
        } else {
            const cookieValue = Cookies.get(key);
            if (cookieValue != null) return JSON.parse(cookieValue);
        }

        if (typeof defaultValue === "function") {
            return defaultValue();
        } else {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (value === undefined) {
            if (storageObject) {
                return storageObject.removeItem(key);
            } else {
                return Cookies.remove(key, options);
            }
        }

        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
        if (storageObject) {
            storageObject.setItem(key, jsonValue);
        } else {
            Cookies.set(key, jsonValue, options);
        }
    }, [key, value, storageObject, options]);

    const remove = useCallback(() => {
        setValue(undefined);
    }, []);

    return [value, setValue, remove];
};

export {
    useLocalStorage,
    useSessionStorage,
    useCookiesStorage
};

frontend/src/pages/Login.jsx
import '../assets/css/login.css';
import { Button, Col, Container, Form, Image, InputGroup, Row, Stack } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GetUser, SignIn } from '../utils/Auth';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { useCookiesStorage } from '../hooks/useStorage';
import UserContext from '../UserContext';

function Login() {
    const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [uidValue, setUidValue] = useState('');
    const [upassValue, setUpassValue] = useState('');
    const [,setToken] = useCookiesStorage('__Secure-auth.session-token', null, {httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'Strict'});

    async function LoginUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Logging in',
            didOpen: () => {
                Swal.showLoading();
            },
            text: 'Please wait',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
        const response = await SignIn(uidValue, upassValue); // Returns response message and token
        
        if (!response || !response.token) {
            Swal.close();
            Swal.fire({
                title: `${response.message}!`,
                icon: 'error',
                text: 'Try again',
                timer: 2000,
                timerProgressBar: false,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false
            });
        }
        else {
            setToken(response.token); // Set the Cookie '__Secure-auth.session-token'
            const user = await GetUser(response.token); // returns user details
            
            if (!user || !user._id) {
                Swal.close();
                Swal.fire({
                    title: `${response.message}!`,
                    icon: 'error',
                    text: 'Try again',
                    timer: 2000,
                    timerProgressBar: false,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    allowOutsideClick: false
                });
            }
            else {
                Swal.close();
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Login successful!',
                    icon: 'success',
                    text: 'Redirecting to dashboard, please wait...',
                    timer: 2000,
                    timerProgressBar: false,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    allowOutsideClick: false
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
                        setUidValue('');
                        setUpassValue('');
                        setUser({ // Sets user context with details from fetch request
                            uid: user._id,
                            user: user.username,
                            role: user.role
                        });
                        navigate('/dashboard');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    return (...rest of code);
};

export default Login;

frontend/src/utils/Auth.js
async function SignIn(username, password) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user/sign-in`, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        }
        else {
            const error = await response.json();
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        Swal.close();
        Swal.fire({
            title: error.message,
            icon: 'error',
            timer: 2000,
            timerProgressBar: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    }
};

async function GetUser(token) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
        
        if (response.ok) {
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        }
        else {
            const error = await response.json();
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};

I hope someone could help me with what I am doing wrong, I am fairly new to React JS and studying through project based learning. Additionally, here is some of my backend codes:
backend/controllers/userController.js
const UserSignIn = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const userAgent = req.useragent;
    const userIp = req.ip;

    if (!username || !password) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error('Fill out all fields');
    }

    await connectToDatabase();
    const client = getClient();
    const db = client.db(process.env.MONGODB_COLLECTION);
    const userCollection = db.collection('users');
    const filter = { username: username };

    const user = await userCollection.findOne(filter);
    if (!user) {
        await disconnectToDatabase();
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error('User does not exist');
    }

    const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isPasswordMatch) {
        await disconnectToDatabase();
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error('Password does not match');
    }

    const generatedToken = await auth.createAccessToken(user, userIp, userAgent);

    await disconnectToDatabase();

    res.cookie('__Secure-auth.session-token', generatedToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'Strict'});
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Login successful', token: generatedToken });
});

// Get User Details
const GetUserDetails = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({
            title: 'Unauthorized',
            message: 'No token provided'
        });
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Verify and decode token
        const decoded = await auth.decodeToken(token);
        if (!decoded || !decoded.user) {
            res.status(401).json({
                title: 'Unauthorized',
                message: 'Invalid token'
            });
            return;
        }

        res.status(200).json(decoded.user);
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            title: 'Unauthorized',
            message: 'Failed to authenticate token',
            stackTrace: error.message
        });
    }
});

backend/middleware/Authentication.js
const expressAsyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const { v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { importJWK, CompactSign, CompactEncrypt, compactDecrypt, jwtVerify } = require('jose');

// Import the RSA keys
const privateKey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'privateKey.json'), 'utf8'));
const publicKey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'publicKey.json'), 'utf8'));

// Helper function to create an access token
const createAccessToken = expressAsyncHandler(async (user, userIp, userAgent) => {
    try {
        const { password, createdAt, updatedAt, ...userData } = user;

        const now = new Date();
        const endOfDay = new Date(now);
        endOfDay.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
        const expiresInSeconds = Math.floor((endOfDay - now) / 1000);

        // JWT payload
        const jwtPayload = {
            iss: 'havok gaming',
            sub: userData._id.toString(),
            exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresInSeconds,
            iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
            jti: uuidv4(),
            user: userData,
            ip: userIp || 'unknown',
            userAgent: userAgent.source || 'unknown',
            role: userData.role
        };

        // Create the signed JWT
        const privateKeyJwk = await importJWK(privateKey, 'RS256');
        const jwt = await new CompactSign(new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(jwtPayload)))
            .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT' })
            .sign(privateKeyJwk);

        // Encrypt the signed JWT
        const publicKeyJwk = await importJWK(publicKey, 'RSA-OAEP-256');
        const encryptedToken = await new CompactEncrypt(new TextEncoder().encode(jwt))
            .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'RSA-OAEP-256', enc: 'A256GCM' })
            .encrypt(publicKeyJwk);

        return encryptedToken;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error creating access token');
    }
});

// Middleware function to verify the token's validity
const verifyToken = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

        if (!token) {
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error('No token provided');
        }

        const privateKeyJwk = await importJWK(privateKey, 'RSA-OAEP-256');
        const { plaintext } = await compactDecrypt(token, privateKeyJwk);

        // Verify JWT signature
        const jwt = new TextDecoder().decode(plaintext);
        const publicKeyJwkForVerify = await importJWK(publicKey, 'RS256');
        const { payload } = await jwtVerify(jwt, publicKeyJwkForVerify);

        if (payload.exp < Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)) {
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error('Token expired');
        }

        next();
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(401);
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Invalid token');
    }
});

// Helper function to decode the token
const decodeToken = expressAsyncHandler(async (token) => {
    try {
        const privateKeyJwk = await importJWK(privateKey, 'RSA-OAEP-256');
        const { plaintext } = await compactDecrypt(token, privateKeyJwk);

        // Decode JWT payload
        const jwt = new TextDecoder().decode(plaintext);
        const publicKeyJwkForVerify = await importJWK(publicKey, 'RS256');
        const { payload } = await jwtVerify(jwt, publicKeyJwkForVerify);

        return payload;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error decoding token');
    }
});

module.exports = {
    createAccessToken,
    verifyToken,
    decodeToken
};

backend/routes/userRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { UserSignIn, GetUserDetails } = require('../controllers/userController');
const { verifyToken } = require('../middleware/Authentication');
const { ValidateUserRequestBody } = require('../middleware/RequestBodyValidator');


router.route('/sign-in').post(ValidateUserRequestBody, UserSignIn);

router.route('/').get(verifyToken, GetUserDetails);

module.exports = router;


Please, can you provide the minimal code snippet?

If you're having trouble setting cookies with httpOnly and secure flags using js-cookie, note that httpOnly cookies cannot be managed via JavaScript due to security reasons.

Remove httpOnly for Testing: Temporarily remove the httpOnly flag to ensure the cookie is being set and visible in the browser's developer tools.
Check HTTPS: Ensure you're running your app over HTTPS if using the secure flag.
Verify Backend Settings: Ensure your backend is setting the cookie correctly with the desired flags.

Here's how you might set a cookie in Express.js:
res.cookie('__Secure-auth.session-token', token, {
httpOnly: true,
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // Use true in production
sameSite: 'Strict'
});
For testing, adjust flags as needed to verify functionality.
